# Adding two UITableViews in one UIVIewController programmatically and want to change the View of Controller with UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: The GIF Result of what the problem is]I want to change the View of my ViewController based on 2 tableVIews with segmentedControl. I have reached it with programmatic approach. I created two TableViews and One SegmentedControl. But When I change the segmentedControl it stays on the same Index but changing the View. I have to tap twice on each Segment to reach it. Why it is happening?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureFirstTableView()
    }

    var firstTableView = UITableView()
    var secondTableView = UITableView()

    func configureFirstTableView() {
        firstTableView.frame = self.view.frame
        firstTableView.delegate = self
        firstTableView.dataSource = self

        firstTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FirstCell")
        view.addSubview(firstTableView)
    }

    func configureSecondTableView() {
        secondTableView.frame = self.view.frame
        secondTableView.delegate = self
        secondTableView.dataSource = self

        secondTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SecondCell")
        view.addSubview(secondTableView)
    }

    func configureSegmentedControl() -> UISegmentedControl {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: view.frame.width - 10, height: 30))
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "First", at: 0, animated: false)
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Second", at: 1, animated: false)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeSegmentedControlValue(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return segmentedControl
    }

    @objc func changeSegmentedControlValue(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            print("1")
            configureFirstTableView()
        case 1:
            print("2")
            configureSecondTableView()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count: Int?
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            count = 3
            return count!
        } else if tableView == secondTableView {
            count = 4
            return count!
        }

        return count!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == firstTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "First"
            return cell
        } else if tableView == secondTableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Second"
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.addSubview(configureSegmentedControl())
        return v
    }

}
```

Comment: Use one table view. Simply update the data source/delegate when the segment changes.

Comment: @rmaddy. The problem is that I need 4 tableVIews, which will have custom tableVIew cells. Two of them will have tableviewCell and 2of them will have collectionVIew in tableViewCell. That's why I need very different data in one VIewController and I want to change that tableVIews with segmented Control. I couldn't get my issue with one tableView